# KnockoutJS uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js

I am working with Web API 2.2, and Knockout JS, and I am getting the following error in my web page:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding
"submit: function (){return ChangePassword }"
Message: ChangePassword is not defined
```

I already checked other responses, and [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981098/uncaught-referenceerror-unable-to-process-binding-with-ajax#) and verified that my casing is correct.

My Knockout JS functions file is called app.js, here is the ChangePassword function:

```
self.ChangePassword = function () {
    self.result = ('');

    var data = {
        //grant_type: 'password',
        OldPassword : self.oldPassword(),
        NewPassword: self.newPassword()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Account/ChangePassword',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.result('Done!');
    }).fail(showError);
}
```

Binded at the bottom of function AppViewModel as:

```
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

The html calls it like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<form data-bind="submit: ChangePassword">
    <h3>Password change</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" data-bind="value: oldPassword" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" data-bind="value: newPassword" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change Password</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm really at a loss here, thanks for any help in advance.

edit: Here is the full app.js class:

```
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;
var tokenKey = 'accessToken';

//----------------------------------------
self.result = ko.observable();
self.user = ko.observable();

self.registerEmail = ko.observable();
self.registerPassword = ko.observable();
self.registerPassword2 = ko.observable();

self.loginEmail = ko.observable();
self.loginPassword = ko.observable();

self.oldPassword = ko.observable();
self.newPassword = ko.observable();
self.newEmail = ko.observable();
//----------------------------------------

// Show Error
function showError(jqXHR) {
    self.result(jqXHR.status + ': ' + jqXHR.statusText);
}

// Test API
self.callApi = function () {
    self.result('');

    var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
    var headers = {};
    if (token) {
        headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/values',
        headers: headers
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.result(data);
    }).fail(showError);
}

// ------------------- Account Methods ------------------- \\

// User info
// External
/*self.userInfo = function () {
    self.result = ('');

    var data = {
       Email: self.registerEmail
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/Account/UserInfo',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }).done(function(){
        self.result(data);
    }).fail(showError);
}*/

// Change Password
self.ChangePassword = function () {
    self.result = ('');

    var data = {
        //grant_type: 'password',
        OldPassword : self.oldPassword(),
        NewPassword: self.newPassword()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Account/ChangePassword',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.result('Done!');
    }).fail(showError);
}

// Register
self.register = function () {
    self.result('');

    var data = {
        Email: self.registerEmail(),
        Password: self.registerPassword(),
        ConfirmPassword: self.registerPassword2()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Account/Register',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.result("Done!");
    }).fail(showError);
}

// Login
self.login = function () {
    self.result('');

    var loginData = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        userName: self.loginEmail(),
        password: self.loginPassword()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Token',
        data: loginData
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.user(data.userName);
        // Cache the access token in session storage.
        sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
    }).fail(showError);
}

// Logout
self.logout = function () {
    self.user('');
    sessionStorage.removeItem(tokenKey)
}


// Testing
self.Test = function () {
    self.result('');

    var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
    var headers = {};
    if (token) {
        headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/scheduler/Test',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        headers: headers,
        data: {}
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.result('Done!');
    }).fail(showError);
 }
}
// Apply the bindings
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: `ChangePassword` is not in scope view model that are bound to your html. can you show your entire view model hierarchy ?

Comment: @Matt.kaaj I added the full app.js class. The login, register, logout, and Call API functions all work

Comment: Try replacing ChangePassword with console.log($root) and check the output.

Comment: It turns out it wasn't a Knockout JS or Web API issue, rather it was the browser caching the old version. Thanks for the help guys.